# Syntax Error: Unexpected T_USE when i'm using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, cpanel

Hi so i'm been trying out PHPMailer since i can't run the mail() function of PHP, But i have an error when i'm using the sample codes that is been posted in GitHub i'm getting an unexpected T_USE i'll comment it out in the code. And since i have searched youtube for some tutorial i does require me to require the PHPMailerAutoLoad.php but i search the directory of the PHPMailer but didn't find that file.

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; // so in this line i have an error

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txJdi.png)

[Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAmV2.png)

Comment: Use statements are only valid at the start of scripts. Can't just throw them anywhere.

Comment: Can you elaborate it more?

Comment: Don't put `use`&`require` in a function.